# Reference for modularity of the Andrews–Gordon–Rogers–Ramanujan identities?

Tags: modular-forms, partitions, theta-functions, q-series

The right-hand side of the identity https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Andrews-GordonIdentity.html is a $q$-series $\frac{(q^i,q^{2k+1-i},q^{2k+1};q^{2k+1})_\infty}{(q;q)_\infty}$; is there a reference of its modularity? As Somos's [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3132502) to [Modular forms and the Roger-Ramanujan identities: How??](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1754128/modular-forms-and-the-roger-ramanujan-identities-how) suggests, the case of $k=i=2$ is already not a trivial consequence of "expressing it as an eta-quotient".

Comment: Your link for "the answer" went to a question; but the question has only one answer, so I assume that was what you meant.  I edited accordingly.